# How to land on All view in object page in navigation lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigationmixin.navigate

In this code below I am getting 'Recent' view landing page on clicking the url. Even when we remove filtername, then also it's same. Please suggest the filterName for All view

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: 'SampleObject__c',
            actionName: 'list'
        },
        state: {
            filterName: 'list' 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the All view is a custom list and the ID depends on the current ORG, you can check on the link or in the List View metadata.
[image: List example]